# Combining multiple condition in single case statement in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

According to the following description I have to frame a `CASE...END` statement in SQL server , help me to frame a complex `CASE...END` statement to fulfill the following condition.

```
if PAT_ENT.SCR_DT is not null and PAT_ENTRY.ELIGIBILITY is null then display display 'Favor'
if PAT_ENT.SCR_DT is not null and PAT_ENTRY.EL is equal to No, display 'Error'
if PAT_ENTRY.EL is Yes and DS.DES is equal to null or OFF, display 'Active'
if DS.DES is equal to N, display 'Early Term'
if DS.DES is equal to Y, display 'Complete'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can put the condition after the `WHEN` clause, like so:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN PAT_ENT.SCR_DT is not null and PAT_ENTRY.ELIGIBILITY is null THEN 'Favor'
    WHEN PAT_ENT.SCR_DT is not null and PAT_ENTRY.EL = 'No' THEN 'Error'
    WHEN PAT_ENTRY.EL = 'Yes' and ISNULL(DS.DES, 'OFF') = 'OFF' THEN 'Active'
    WHEN DS.DES = 'N' THEN 'Early Term'
    WHEN DS.DES = 'Y' THEN 'Complete'
  END
FROM
  ....
```

Of course, the argument could be made that complex rules like this belong in your business logic layer, not in a stored procedure in the database...

Answer (score 0):

```
select ROUND(CASE 

WHEN  CONVERT( float, REPLACE( isnull( value1,''),',',''))='' AND CONVERT( float, REPLACE( isnull( value2,''),',',''))='' then  CONVERT( float, REPLACE( isnull( value3,''),',',''))

WHEN  CONVERT( float, REPLACE( isnull( value1,''),',',''))='' AND CONVERT( float, REPLACE( isnull( value2,''),',',''))!='' then  CONVERT( float, REPLACE( isnull( value3,''),',',''))

WHEN  CONVERT( float, REPLACE( isnull( value1,''),',',''))!='' AND CONVERT( float, REPLACE( isnull( value2,''),',',''))='' then  CONVERT( float, REPLACE( isnull( value3,''),',',''))

else CONVERT( float, REPLACE(isnull( value1,''),',','')) end,0)  from Tablename where    ID="123"
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.