# Case Statements with conditionals in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to tweak the following SQL so the query will output the type of card (visa, mastercard, etc) as PaymentMethod instead of Credit Card.

```
CASE    WHEN pm.PaymentType = 1 THEN 'Cash'
        WHEN pm.PaymentType = 2 THEN 'Check' 
        WHEN pm.PaymentType = 3 THEN 'Credit Card'
        WHEN pm.PaymentType = 4 THEN 'EFT'
        WHEN pm.PaymentType = 5 THEN 'Money Order'
        WHEN pm.PaymentType = 6 THEN 'Conveyance'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
        END AS PaymentMethod,
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction. I tried adding a second conditional to my case statement, but it fails out to 'Unknown' for all payment types of 3.

```
CASE    WHEN pm.PaymentType = 1 THEN 'Cash'
        WHEN pm.PaymentType = 2 THEN 'Check' 
        WHEN pm.PaymentType = 3 and pm.CardTypeMId = 1 THEN 'American Express'
        WHEN pm.PaymentType = 3 and pm.CardTypeMId = 2 THEN 'Discover'
        WHEN pm.PaymentType = 3 and pm.CardTypeMId = 3 THEN 'Mastercard'
        WHEN pm.PaymentType = 3 and pm.CardTypeMId = 4 THEN 'Visa'
        WHEN pm.PaymentType = 4 THEN 'EFT'
        WHEN pm.PaymentType = 5 THEN 'Money Order'
        WHEN pm.PaymentType = 6 THEN 'Conveyance'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
        END AS PaymentMethod,
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Sounds like `pm.CardTypeMId` may not be 1, 2, 3 or 4?

Comment: Duplicate IMO, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043154/combining-multiple-condition-in-single-case-statement-in-sql-server

Comment: Looks fine to me, ANSI SQL compliant syntax. (Try a CASE in the outer CASE's if 3 then.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could simplify this quite a bit.

```
CASE pm.PaymentType 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Cash'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Check' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 
        CASE pm.CardTypeMId 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'American Express'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Discover'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Mastercard'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Visa'
        END
    WHEN 4 THEN 'EFT'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Money Order'
    WHEN 6 THEN 'Conveyance'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
END AS PaymentMethod
```

Comment: you *can* simplify it like that, but their original query is syntactically correct, so if `pm.CardTypeMId` doesn't have a value of 1-4, it's still going to return `NULL`.  Not sure why this has so many upvotes when it doesn't really address the main issue, but I guess it would at least confirm if there was a problem with the data.

Comment: Yes the original is syntactically correct. Not really sure either why this has so many upvotes. I didn't mention anything about if pm.CardTypeMId not matching since that had been covered in the comments already. Perhaps seeing NULL instead of 'Unknown' either provides the functionality they wanted or let them see the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested CASE

```
WHEN pm.PaymentType = 3 THEN 
 Case 
    WHEN pm.CardTypeMId = 1 THEN 'American Express'
    WHEN pm.CardTypeMId = 2 THEN 'Discover'
    WHEN pm.CardTypeMId = 3 THEN 'Mastercard'
    WHEN pm.CardTypeMId = 4 THEN 'Visa'
    END as CreditCard
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because `pm.CardTypeMId` is not equal to 1, 2 3 or 4 when `pm.PaymentType = 3`.

Just try `WHEN pm.PaymentType = 3 THEN 'Visa'` for the Visa line

Answer (score 0):

It seems obvious to say that you are not passing in 1, 2, 3 or 4 to pm.CardTypeID.
You should therefore add an else clause to catch this as below:

```
Case pm.PaymentType 
    When 1 Then 'Cash'
    When 2 Then 'Check'
    When 4 Then 'EFT'
    When 5 Then 'Money Order'
    When 6 Then 'Conveyance' 
    When 3 Then Case pm.CardTypeMId 
                    When 1 Then 'American Express'
                    When 2 Then 'Discover'
                    When 3 Then 'Mastercard'
                    When 4 Then 'Visa'
                           Else 'Other Credit Card'
                End
           Else 'Unknown'
End As PaymentMethod
```