# Choosing 2 different values in a CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle

A situation has occurred where i need to show  a different value based on whether or not something has been Paid. Here is the problem:

I have a table which contains different products. These products change based on whether they are paid. So originally we will have this data row in a table

```
NAME    DESCRIPTION    CODE        DELIVERY
John     Paid          BookPaid    Posted
```

If one of our products has Paid in the Description column we need to look at a what the Delivery is but if it hasnt been paid, we wiil need to look at what the delivery type is, so it would look like this

```
NAME    DESCRIPTION    CODE        DELIVERY
John     Pending       Book         Postal
```

My approach to this is looking into CASE Statements but the issue is it requires 2 conditions and in the interested of saving time i didnt want multiple CASE statement selections kind of like:

```
CASE WHEN DESCRIPTION = 'Paid'
     THEN NAME, DESCRIPTION, DELIVERY
```

Essentially saying when its paid use this datarow that contains the matching information based on the specified CASE condition. I am having trouble with the logic to this

Comment: Can you not just do an IF/ELSE?

Comment: Could this be what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3043154/4636715

Comment: What is a "Product"?  Your question is unclear (to me) because you use terminology not reflected in the data structure.

Comment: @dbajtr Possibly, i will try working with that. vahdet not quite, it needs to basically return a multiiple specified rows based on that condtions. Gordon Lindoff It is an umbrella term describing the information that these row values relate to i.e a product has a name, description, code and delivery value

Comment: I think more info is needed to be able to provide a meaningful answer. What columns do you want when a product is not yet paid? Where are you putting this in your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not directly use in that way. Write manual case for each column if you want.

example:

```
CASE WHEN DESCRIPTION = 'Paid' 
THEN NAME end ,
CASE WHEN DESCRIPTION = 'Paid' 
THEN DESCRIPTION end,
CASE WHEN DESCRIPTION = 'Paid' 
THEN DELIVERY end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use case in column selection like this

```
select name, description,  --common columns
case DESCRIPTION  --specific columns
when 'Paid' then DELIVERY 
ELSE OTHER_COLUMN END as delivery 
from products
```